# base video src for thumbnails

Tags: jquery, video-streaming, relative-path

after much digging, i was able to set a base src for my iframes, eliminating the need for base target and base href in one fell swoop.  not taking credit for it, i just altered some existing fiddles to suit my needs.

https://jsfiddle.net/1fj3gq9s/2/

```
HTML

<iframe frameborder="0" width="700" height="430"></iframe>
<br><br>
<div class="vidlist">
    <a vid="8PdR1_pVNBE">Supernatural Season 1 Episode 1</a> 
    <a vid="lHB2OuQ1AqY">Supernatural Season 1 Episode 2</a>
</div>

jQuery

$('.vidlist a').click(function() {
    $('iframe').attr('src', 'https://openload.co/embed/' + $(this).attr('vid'));
    return false;
});

CSS

.vidlist a {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: blue;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

works great for links, but not for setting the base path for video and image thumbnails.  I am using b-lazy for lazy loading videos, which uses the data-src attribute.  I would like to shorten all my links by setting a base path for the videos, hopefully not disabling b-lazy in the process.

This is what obviously doesn't work

```
HTML

<div class="vidlist">
    <video data-src="movie.ogg"></video>
</div>

jQuery

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.vidlist video').attr('src', 'http://www.w3schools.com/html/' + $(this).attr('data-src'));
});

CSS

.vidlist video {
    width: 320px;
    height: 180px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Being new to web development, I frequently just do not know how to ask the right questions.  What am I doing wrong?  Is what I am trying to do feasible?  Is there a workaround if not which will allow lazy loading?

Answer (score 0):

Html.

```
<div class="vidlist">
    <video data-src="movie.ogg">
    </video>
</div>
```

jQuery. Best use `data` method to get `data-src`

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var targetSrc = 'http://www.w3schools.com/html/' + $('.vidlist video').data('src');
  $('.vidlist video').append('<source src="' + targetSrc + '" type="video/ogg">');
  $('.vidlist video')[0].play(); //Access to js api video object
});
```

CSS. Ensure that your video element has width and height

```
video {
   width: 400px;
   height: 300px;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks hokusai.  unfortunately, it didn't work     https://jsfiddle.net/musghb43/

Comment: Edited, try add source tag by jquery